# How to Divide the result of a 2D String Array by the length of the subarray?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

How to Divide the result of a 2D Array by the length of the subarray. I need help on the third question. Where is asking to enter the missing line of code to find the average time of each runner. Use the averageVal.

Here's the question "We’ve given you a variable named averageVal that currently stores 0. Edit that line of code to find the average time of each runner."

```
public class RowMajor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Given runner lap data
        double[][] times = {{64.791, 75.972, 68.950, 79.039, 73.006, 74.157}, {67.768, 69.334, 70.450, 67.667, 75.686, 76.298}, {72.653, 77.649, 74.245, 62.121, 63.379, 79.354}};
        
        // Replace the incorrect for loop headers, use the iterators 'outer' and 'inner' for the outer and inner loops
        double runnerTime = 0.0;
        for(int outer = 0; outer < times.length; outer++) {
            runnerTime = 0.0;
            for(int inner = 0; inner < times[outer].length; inner++) {
                System.out.println("Runner index: " + outer + ", Time index: " + inner);
                // Enter the missing line of code to sum up the values in each row. Use the variable runnerTime
                runnerTime += times[outer][inner];
        
            }

            // I need help with this question below.
            // Enter the missing line of code to find the average time of each runner. Use the variable averageVal
            double averageVal = 0;
            // Below is what I tried but it keep showing an error "The correct average time for runner 0 was not printed to the console."
            double averageTime = runnerTime / times[outer].length;

            System.out.println("Sum of runner " + outer + " times: " + runnerTime + averageTime);
            System.out.println("Average of runner " + outer + ": " + averageVal + averageTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure the your output match the required output so maybe there missing space or any symbol

Comment: The question where I need to enter the missing line of code to find the average time of each runner. Use the variable averageVal.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line already did the job

```
double averageTime = runnerTime / times[outer].length;
```

The problem is when you print it with

```
System.out.println("Average of runner " + outer + ": " + averageVal + averageTime);
```

`averageVal` and `averageTime` are not added together (I do not understand why you add them though). They are appended.

e.g.

```
    int one = 1;
    int three = 3;
    System.out.println("" + one + three);
```

The output is 13, not 4.

The reason is, when you print a primitive together when String, primitive will be [auto boxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) to Integer and the statement become `"".toString() + one.toString() + three.toString()`. Since `toString()` return string, operator `+` will just chain them.

I tidy up your code and post the output below

```
public class RowMajor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Given runner lap data
        double[][] times = { { 64.791, 75.972, 68.950, 79.039, 73.006, 74.157 },
                { 67.768, 69.334, 70.450, 67.667, 75.686, 76.298 },
                { 72.653, 77.649, 74.245, 62.121, 63.379, 79.354 } };

        // Replace the incorrect for loop headers, use the iterators 'outer' and 'inner'
        // for the outer and inner loops
        double runnerTime = 0.0;
        for (int outer = 0; outer < times.length; outer++) {
            runnerTime = 0.0;
            for (int inner = 0; inner < times[outer].length; inner++) {
                System.out.println("Runner index: " + outer + ", Time index: " + inner);
                // Enter the missing line of code to sum up the values in each row. Use the
                // variable runnerTime
                runnerTime += times[outer][inner];

            }

            // I need help with this question below.
            // Enter the missing line of code to find the average time of each runner. Use
            // the variable averageVal
            double averageVal = runnerTime / times[outer].length;

            System.out.println("Sum of runner " + outer + " times: " + runnerTime);
            System.out.println("Average of runner " + outer + ": " + averageVal);

        }
    }
}
```

Console output

```
Runner index: 0, Time index: 0
Runner index: 0, Time index: 1
Runner index: 0, Time index: 2
Runner index: 0, Time index: 3
Runner index: 0, Time index: 4
Runner index: 0, Time index: 5
Sum of runner 0 times: 435.9149999999999
Average of runner 0: 72.65249999999999
Runner index: 1, Time index: 0
Runner index: 1, Time index: 1
Runner index: 1, Time index: 2
Runner index: 1, Time index: 3
Runner index: 1, Time index: 4
Runner index: 1, Time index: 5
Sum of runner 1 times: 427.2030000000001
Average of runner 1: 71.20050000000002
Runner index: 2, Time index: 0
Runner index: 2, Time index: 1
Runner index: 2, Time index: 2
Runner index: 2, Time index: 3
Runner index: 2, Time index: 4
Runner index: 2, Time index: 5
Sum of runner 2 times: 429.401
Average of runner 2: 71.56683333333334
```

Comment: Thanks the solution work. Now I see where my problem was. I was suppose to set "runnerTime / times[outer].length;" on the place of the zero after the = sign. Instead I created a new double variable.

Comment: I was confused too, averageVal and averageTIme